# How to sort arrays with multiple items - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

What I am trying to do is sort my three arrays (array1, array2, and array3) in order by their 0th term, to display the following.

```
1, banana, 2, grapes, 3, oranges.
```

This is my code, but I can't figure out how to get it to sort the way I want.

```
var array1 = ["1", "banana"];
var array2 = ["3", "oranges"];
var array3 = ["2", "grapes"];
var array4 = [];

function myFunction(){
    array4.push(array1, array2, array3);
    alert((array4).sort(function(a, b){return a-b}));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the elements based on `[0]`th index.

```
(array4).sort(function(a, b){return a[0]-b[0]})
```

---

```
function myFunction(){
    array4.push(array1, array2, array3);
    alert((array4).sort(function(a, b){return a[0]-b[0]}));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace Your code with this :

```
var array1 = ["1", "banana"];
var array2 = ["3", "oranges"];
var array3 = ["2", "grapes"];
var array4 = [];

function myFunction()
{
    array4.push(array1, array2, array3);
    alert(array4.sort());
}
```

You **Output** will be **1,banana,2,grapes,3,oranges**

Comment: Does not work for `1,3,21` gives output as `1,21,3` : http://jsfiddle.net/7frhj2dv/